# upgrade ESLint to ECMA6 Brackets IDE

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, adobe-brackets

### Background

I recently switched to using Brackets IDE to code on JavaScript. Upon realizing the default linter of Brackets was a very outdated version of JSLint, I followed some documentation and ended up installing the more versatile [ESLint](https://github.com/zaggino/brackets-eslint).

### Problem

The problem is that this linter is only built for ECMA5, and does not even recognize the usage of keywords like `const`.

There are some efforts from the community to improve JSLint into accepting ECMA6, but since I have been using ESLint in Cloud9 IDE for quite a while, I would like to keep it.

### What I tried

My reaction was to add the [rules manually](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/), in some `eslint` configuration file, but after searching for it I couldn't find it.

### Question

1. Is there a way to update ESLint rules on brackets IDE? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[An issue in the brackets-eslint project](https://github.com/zaggino/brackets-eslint/issues/46) says the extension will pick up ESLint's standard `.eslintrc` configuration files. Try putting this `.eslintrc.json` in your project's root directory:

```
{
    "root": true,

    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6
    },

    "extends": "eslint:recommended"
}
```

You can find more options in ESLint's [configuring guide](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring). You can also run `eslint --init` in your project's root directory to have ESLint walk you through setting up an initial configuration.

Comment: I ended up following the eslint configuration steps you recommended in your links and I it worked for me.